# Typescript loses undefined context with forEach or map

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a Typescript interface representing a user query. As such, it contains mostly optional fields:

```js
interface InputData {
    fieldOne?: {
        requiredField: {
            key: string;
            values?: string[];
        }
    }
    fieldTwo?: {
        etc?: string;
    }
}
```

Using the `--strictNullChecks` flag with Typescript, I have to make sure that each property is not undefined before accessing it:

```js
function do_something(input: InputData): void {
    const messages: string[] = [];
    if (input.fieldOne !== undefined) {
        if (input.fieldOne.requiredField.values !== undefined) {
            console.log(input.fieldOne.requiredField.values):
            // no errors
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I try and use an optional field inside of a `forEach` or `map`, even after checking if it is undefined, I recieve an error:

```js
if (input.fieldOne !== undefined) {
    if (input.fieldOne.requiredField.values !== undefined) {
        input.fieldOne.requiredField.values.forEach(v => {
            messages.push(`${v} ${input.fieldOne.requiredField.key}`);
            // error!
        });
    }
}
```

> "input.fieldOne" | Object is possibly undefined. (2532)

Here it seems like Typescript is "losing" the context that this field is not undefined inside of the `forEach` or `map` call.

How can I fix this error? Is there a better way to handle these undefined fields? Thanks!

[(Here is a link to this error in the Typescript Playground.)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=65&pln=14&pc=118#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgA4FcwBE5hzIDeAUMhcjMBADYAmA8iBAPwBcJ5lPUEAjlmB96AMRoNOZHjMoBrCAE9OAZzBRQAcwDc3WTwBucWlggqOyNRpCaA2gF1d%205AF89r0m9IwsIBGGAAexBkekCAfRVAgFsIMAALLQAKUGwwTnQ0-EIASk4DQOB6Lh4EYLVkWJUVOE0zVXUtB2QAXmQHJ0pgGGQUzBwAOmo6JhZkAEIWtt96CGoWehyS-W7e1MHhhmYIAb5BYQgxCXoBoxMzCankGbnQQ6XpZ0oqmrqVAewVeKSB3-WwIbHba7ARCETiEanYymd7ROAYJIGVoAPmQAAMACTEAwuZBY-6AkbAvZgw4QhgDBSKFxonI5TpPZAAeiZyAJm1GOxJByOkLOMKGgSgAFFEN8kS1US9amYPlgvklMdjcfj%20gCOcTQTzyScqTS6QyZG4eMbKGUQFFaDtaIFNElpW96Z5SKRzRV-uFghAMmrskQ2o8KBqWFJ3LwteDjqHGRQqZwAOQAZWA0WC8YANGH9Pz6u14-E6DaM8h45pAoF6AAjRQQeP2LMUU2Nzy6V3lMBstXhMAAd0CPqyBH9JBcrbCkRicUSNj6aU9LCd46isQSyQ9vcC9KAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Non-Null` assertion operator (`!`). You'll be telling typescript compiler: "Trust me, I know what I'm doing."

```js
console.log(input.fieldOne!.requiredField.values):
```

Another approach would be creating another variable before the `forEach` statement, where typescript compiler still trust on `if` scope:

```
if (input.fieldOne) {
  const requiredField = input.fieldOne.requiredField;
  requiredField.values.forEach(v => messages.push(`${v} ${requiredField.key}`));
}
```

A third approach would be retesting `input.fieldOne` inside the `forEach` loop. It would cause a performance decrease though:

```
if (input.fieldOne) {
  input.fieldOne.requiredField.values.forEach(v => {
    if (input.fieldOne) {
      messages.push(`${v} ${input.fieldOne.requiredField.key}`);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems like this sidesteps the `strictNullChecks` flag, is there a more "compliant" solution? In my current project I've done a lot of refactoring to better respect the strict null-checks capability of the compiler.

Comment: I can think of a couple things and put them on my answer.

Comment: Is seems like TSLint inference keeps thinking that the object could have somehow been set to undefined between the time each line of code is read - which is possible (depending if the data is shared etc).